# Loops and SQL in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I've got the following code that I can't seem to get working:

```
function drawTable($result)
{

    var_dump($result);
    echo '<table border = "1" cellpadding="10">';
    echo '<tr>             
            <th>Album</th>               
            <th>Tracks</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Purchase</th>               
         </tr>';

    foreach($result as &$album) {

        $albumID = $album['Album_ID'];
        var_dump($albumID);

        //echo '<tr><td><img src="' . $resultRow['Image_URL'] . '" width="200px" height="200px"> </td>';

        $tracksQuery = "SELECT Track_Title FROM Track WHERE (Album_ID = '$albumID')";

        var_dump($tracksQuery);

        $DBConnector2 = new DBConnector();

        $tracks = $DBConnector2->getSQL($tracksQuery);

        var_dump($tracks);

        while ($trackTitle = mysqli_fetch_array($tracks)) {
            echo $trackTitle['Track_Title'] . '<br />';

        }
    }

     echo '</table>';
}
```

The var `$result` is a list of `Album_ID`s. I want to iterate over this using a `foreach` and also to run a query to get its associated tracks.

The var_dump gives:

```
object(mysqli_result)#4 (0) { }
```

In addition, the SQL I'm using for $result is

```
SELECT *
FROM Album
ORDER BY Album.Album_Name ASC
```

Very basic. You can see the other SQL use in the loop.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: if the var_dump you are talking about is the first one, then variable $result is empty, your query didn't return any rows..

Comment: Is $result parameter an array or a resource link? No need to use reference variable in foreach.

Comment: @amosrivera I think all of the var_dumps are here, and they are null, except for the first one... @adatapost -  $result whats given back as initial SQL results table (with all Album_IDs)

Comment: What is DBConnector? Please don't mix object and procedural style in your script. It is confusing at least.

Comment: Try to use mysqli_errno( $link ) and mysqli_error($link) to ensure there aren't errors in your query.

Comment: DBConnector is a class with the function getSQL() in it... I'm not experienced in PHP, sorry about that.

Comment: `var_dump` is behaving properly: it's telling you that `$tracks` is an object of type `mysqli_result`, which is true. The actual data that's the result of your query isn't embedded into the object; it's just a handle with which you can iterate over the resultset using `fetch_array` or `fetch_assoc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that $result is the return of a mysql_query function. You can't do that as it is still a reference to a mysql resultset, not the real mysql result.

Instead of using the foreach iteration, use a while loop like the following:

```
while ($album = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 ...
 ...
}
```

I'm not so sure whether in the first place you may pass a mysql result reference in a function but you can give it a try :)

Comment: I'm getting `mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resourc` at the moment. I did try this before and it worked, makes sense now... but I'm still getting an error :/

Comment: I guessed correctly regarding the passing of a mysql resultset pointer to a function. Unfortunately you should run the while loop outside this function and inside the loop pass each $album to this function.

Comment: I've brought the SQL connector into the function now but it's not working. Besides, I already had a working page by passing the result set by reference, so it does work like that.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use foreach with mysqli, that I know of.  Change it to this:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ...
```